# How do I play this?

Tags: guitar, sheet-music

I am trying to play this on the guitar

I am having difficulty understanding the 4th measure  in the picture below. It looks like I have to play a G chord without the 5th (D is missing) and then, silence the middle G string while playing an F note on the D string.

But how do I check if my sound is right? I tried to enter this score into a score writing application (Finale) but did not succeed.

[image: Check measure 5]

Comment: As folks below have mentioned, let it ring! Use your musical taste in these situations - it will sound better than Finale every time (at least with questions of aesthetics)!

By the way, you say you tried to enter the music into Finale but didn't succeed - what happened?

Comment: Hi Ben, I just couldn't figure out how to enter this. When I try to put a quarter note, either my chord is converted to quarter, or (when I click a little on the right) I hear e beep stopping my action..

I tried to use two quarter chords and tie the upper and lower notes, but the result is not what I expected (the chord is played twice, as if the tie did not exist)

Comment: Ahh, OK! You want to use the 'layers' functionality - it allows multiple voices w/ independent rhythms https://www.finalemusic.com/UserManuals/Finale2012Mac/Content/Finale/Tut2EnteringNotes4.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you play the low G with finger 3 (L.H.) you can then play the F on the D string with finger 4. If you play the F with what I call "lazy technique", by putting the fourth finger on slightly flat, it will touch the open G and stop it ringing. While you do this you keep the third finger pressed down on the low G.

To be honest though, it doesn't matter if the open G rings on over the F, as it is still part of the overall harmony, a G7 chord, so it won't sound dissonant. If you do stop the open G it will give the inner part more definition, though, and make it sound like a line, rather than just part of the harmony.

Comment: I think you're spot on with 'let it ring'. Often with guitar music, it sounds better to do this, if all the notes constitute a chord. I've found it in exam pieces (written out without looking too complex)- a pupil, who was taught by someone else, played exactly 'as writ' and it sounded quite disjointed. Letting certain notes ring for longer than written made it smooth out well.

Answer (score 0):

From how I understand it, you play the G(low)-G(middle)-B chord (G major without the 5th) and keep it for half the measure, and then change the middle G to F, pretty much like you said.

You don't 'silence' it, but you keep it for a shorter duration; while you keep the low G and B for 2 beats, you keep the middle G for only 1 beat, then change it to F, which is also kept for 1 beat.